# Left join on broken?

Tags: mysql, left-join

So i had a mysql query which used to work as intended but now i think something has happened and it seems to not work anymore.

What i have is 2 tables that i want to join. "

> users

and

> logs

I want a list of all the user id's(UID) in the "users" table that have **not** logged in today. So i used this query.

```
SELECT users.UID 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN logs 
  ON users.UID = logs.UID 
 AND DATE(logs.SCANTIME )=DATE(SYSDATE()) 
WHERE logs.UID is null
```

The above query used to work but now returns with a list of UID's that are not supposed to be there.

If i look into the log today i can see multiple rows, i have omitted all but one for the sake of saving space.

```
 mysql> SELECT UID, SCANTIME FROM logs WHERE DATE(scantime)=DATE(SYSDATE());
    +------------+---------------------+
    | UID        | SCANTIME            |
    +------------+---------------------+
    .............
    | AA9B351B   | 2017-08-02 06:13:21 |
    .............
    +------------+---------------------+
    63 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So this guy AA9B351B is clearly logged in today. Yet he showes up when i run the query above. Thanks for any replies

Comment: @Dhruv Saxena - LEFT JOIN will return all users but won't the WHERE clause then filter the results so only applicable users are returned.

Comment: Query looks fine. Check `sysdate()` value is rigth considering that client and server may have different time, and timezone can be configured/overrided at several points and levels. Beside that, there are few server side configs that may affect the result of your query.

Comment: Two possibilities I see.  1) time(logs.scantime) isn't returning what you think it is like '6:00' is getting compared to '01:00' and the comparison is at a string level instead of a "time" data type. 2) you more than one record in logs for that user.  at least one of which is today but before 01:00 and after 12:00. If your goal is to only show users with login between 01:00 and 12:00 then an inner join is more appropriate here as others indicate.  What is it you're trying to do?  Find all users who have not logged in today between some hour range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server time may have become incorrect, so SYSDATE is returning the wrong value. Check the system time and also run a SQL query with SYSDATE function replaced with literals (Just to test). Also related to this check the time zone has not changed. If server time wrong then reset.